# OpenGL perspective and lighting not working?

Tags: c++, opengl, perspective, lighting

**EDIT: A few people have said to use glNormal3f() to solve my lighting problem, but I researched and implemented that just now and it didn't change anything at all.**

I'm kind of new to OpenGL so I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I followed the examples in the Red Book as closely as I could and I just can't figure out what's wrong, so I figured I'd try and ask you guys.

I have two problems. One is that, even though I'm sure I'm using glFrustum correctly, it still renders an orthographic scene, and it renders objects that are both in front of and behind the camera for some reason. The other is that, even though I'm pretty sure I'm doing this lighting right (because I followed the example in the book), it's lighting the scene with a uniform color, no shading or anything. Here's my code:

```
#include "GraphicsManager.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>

void GraphicsManager::initialize () {
  fx = 0;
  fy = 0;  
  glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable (GL_LIGHT0);
  glDepthFunc (GL_LEQUAL);
  glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glViewport (0, 0, 800, 600);
  glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity ();
  glFrustum (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);
  glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity ();
}

int GraphicsManager::draw (std::vector<float> buttoninfo) {
  // changing light_position makes no difference
  GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
  int i, j, k;
  fx += buttoninfo[0];
  fy += buttoninfo[1];
  glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f (0.5, 0.5, 0.8);
  glLoadIdentity ();
  glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);�
  glRotatef (buttoninfo[3], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glRotatef (buttoninfo[2], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glTranslatef (-fx, 0, -fy);
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j ++) {
  for (k = 0; k < 5; k ++) {
    glPushMatrix ();
    glTranslatef (i, j, k);
    glBegin (GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
      glVertex3f (0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
      glVertex3f (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
      glVertex3f (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
      glVertex3f (0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
      glVertex3f (0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
      glVertex3f (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd ();
    glPopMatrix ();
  }
  }
  }
  glFlush ();
  return (int)buttoninfo[5];
}
```

Can you help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't why your projection is wrong, but you won't get proper lighting without normals (call `glNormal3f` before every call to `glVertex3f`).

Comment: To deal with lighting you need to supply Normals along with Vertexes. See glNormal3f usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the elements around the origin (0,0,0) but you don't move the "camera" at the begining. so your are looking from the origin point at the scene, which is inside your elements.

try if

```
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity ();
glTranslate3f(0, 0, -10);
```

works to fix it

and for Perspective rendering consider using gluPerspective.
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml

Comment: This makes it so nothing renders at all. Also, I am moving my `camera' away from the origin, with the glTranslatef(-fx, 0, -fy) command. And using gluPerspective() instead of glFrustum() makes no difference.

Comment: ah i didnt see that in your code. maybe because of the rotation you perform? if  i wasn't about to finish my bachelor thesis right now i'd try out that code...

Comment: No that's the scene rotation, it should be there. There's some SDL code I'm not showing that basically makes this a first-person-shooter type system, and the angles and movement are working fine, the problem is it's being orthographic. Actually I can do anything at all to projection matrix and it won't change a thing, it's like it's not even reading it ... even though I know it runs the initialize function ...

Comment: and you are sure the initialize function is called before every frame you render?

Comment: Does it have to be? I was under the impression that you just call it once, and it sets everything until you change it ... I'll call it every frame and see if that helps ... Wow thanks that definitely helped with the lighting. Projection doesn't seem any different though.

Comment: Okay then, everything randomly started working this time for some unknown reason. Been fighting this for a month so I'm glad ^^ Thanks for your help!